# CJ commission detail service api recent response structure

Tags: xml, api, commission-junction, cj

I need to implement Commission Detail Service API in my project. The documentation of CJ commission detail API has no explanation of response structure. This [Commission Detail Service (REST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794311/commission-detail-service-rest) question has the explanation, but now it's outdated because it doesn't contain all response parameters mentioned in CJ documentation. So, if someone is using commission detail API then, please help. I truly appreciate your time and effort. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting no response here. I have raised the ticket on CJ site and this is the response I got.
[image: XML response]

I have written the polling service as well in python. Where I'm calling commission detail api(commission level) and by fetching out original_action_id, again I'm making call to commission detail api(item level) and finally combining both the result in one dictionary. You can find my repo in the given below link.

> https://github.com/arcticOak2/cj-commission-detail-service-api-complete-python-script

Thank you